# Как построить запрос sqlite, чтобы найти...?

Tags: sqlite

У нас есть таблица с тремя колонками `:id int, Num_challenge int  и len int`.
Где `Num_challange` - номер соревнования(в порядке очередности), а `len` - длина прыжка. Как построить запрос, который выдал бы `id` 3х человек, у которых была самая большая разница между прыжком на их последнем соревновании и прыжком на их первом?

Comment: id - это id человека?

Comment: Да, это так....

Answer (score 1):

получилось, мне кажется, сложно

```
select tt.id, abs(t1.len-t2.len) df 
   from 
     (select id, min(Num_challenge) min_nc, max(Num_challenge) max_nc 
         from t group by id) tt
     join t t1 on t1.id=tt.id and t1.Num_challenge=tt.min_nc 
     join t t2 on t2.id=tt.id and t2.Num_challenge=tt.max_nc 
  order by df desc
  limit 3
```

Comment: Это считается уже полчаса)

Comment: ну как-то слишком долго. а большая база?

Comment: 14 тысяч записей.

Comment: да не так уж много

Comment: Я ошибся, 14 тысяч человек, а записей 1,4kk

Comment: @Urbani7 И что в результате?

Comment: @splasg58 В результате сделал микс из sql и питона, все стало работать за секунду.